# Azure DevOps build fails for XAML files

Tags: c#, azure, devops, pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps build for a new class library project which is building correctly (.NET Framework 4.6.2).

I have added some XAML files from another project via Visual Studio and it displayed an error "InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context".  I found that if I changed the XAML file property Build Action to Page that this resolved the issue in Visual Studio and it built fine (this setting was on the original files but is lost when you copy the files over to a new project).

The issue now is that I am getting the same error in the DevOps build on DotNet Build.

Are there additional steps required when building a project that contains XAML files?  Or are there any issues adding XAML files to a class library?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding the following line in your csproj file:

```xml
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

This line instructs the build system to incorporate the WPF targets, which are necessary to create XAML files.

*I have build the XAML WPF app successfully, Refer below:-*

**My yaml code to build XAML WPF app with `dotnet build`:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.x'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Also, As an alternative, ***Instead of dotnetbuild try using VsBuild to build your pipeline*** like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Output:-**

[image]